# How to change root password in kubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, root

I forgot my root password and all other passwords as well. I can't login. I want to log in with grub but can't find a way to get grub and the 'shift' doesn't help. My version is Kubuntu 18.04.

Please help and thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Ask Ubuntu post
[How do I reset a lost administrative password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password)
describes several methods.

**Boot into recovery mode**

- Boot, and *after* the BIOS screen, hold down the left <kbd>Shift</kbd> key.
- In the menu use <kbd>down-arrow</kbd> to select the entry marked "recovery mode"
  and then <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- Use the arrow keys to select **root** and then <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- In the root prompt, remount the filesystem with write permissions:

  ```
  mount -o remount,rw /
  ```
- Use the `passwd root` command to set the password
- Reboot

**Boot into GRUB**

- Enter the boot menu as above by holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> key during boot.
  If this does not work, try to hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> before grub has started
  more than once. Skip the next point.
- Position to *Drop to root shell prompt* and then <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Use `passwd root` to change the password
- Type `exit` to return to the recovery menu
- In the recovery menu, select *resume normal boot*.

If the above two methods did not work for you, more methods are listed in the 
above link.

If none of them worked, GRUB itself may be damaged.
See for example the article
[How to Repair GRUB2 When Ubuntu Won’t Boot](https://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/),
with the difference that you may be able to do `boot-repair` from Linux.

Comment: Quote from original post: _"... and the 'shift' doesn't help"_

Comment: @gronostaj: Which is why I specified exactly when it should be pressed. If this doesn't work at all, then grub itself is damaged and needs to be reinstalled.

Comment: FWIW, I have yet to succeed using `shift` to access the grub menus, I need to hit `Esc` before grub has started. Hitting `Esc` more than once - you end up at the `grub> `  prompt (type quit and press enter to get back).

Comment: Once in grub, the second method can be used.