# Windows and PopOs dual boot - Windows account deleted, can't login?

Tags: windows-10

Trying to login but had made account via uni email, now it's been deleted, so can't login. This is the windows account.

Is there a way to remove the password needed on the account from my PopOS system? Because it's dual boot, i'm thinking perhaps i can access my windows hardrive (separate ssd) to change the accoutn settings?

Just want to play games :(

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Does [this method](https://superuser.com/questions/1462267/how-to-change-root-password-in-kubuntu) help?

Comment: its' windows that has the issue

Comment: Unclear: PopOS is Linux. Please [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1625473/edit) your post and explain the problem with more detail.